# How to increase increasing mem_limit using sphinx search engine with rails 2.3.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I am using rails 2.3.8 with sphinx search, am getting the following error message while rebuilding the indexes

```
indexing index 'model_core'...
collected 882974 docs, 755.7 MB
collected 959418 attr values
sorted 1.9 Mvalues, 100.0% done
**WARNING: sort_hits: merge_block_size=140 kb too low, increasing mem_limit may improve**
```

here is my configuration file,

```
sphinx.yml
development:
  port: 9316
test:
  port: 9314
production:
  port: 9312
```

Please help me how to configure in sphinx.yml file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
development:
  port: 9316
  mem_limit: 128M
test:
  port: 9314
  mem_limit: 128M
production:
  port: 9312
  mem_limit: 128M
```

Here you've got more info about it: http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/advanced_config.html